# Get width of Text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

how can I get the `width` of a `Text` component?

I want to make my `Button` that is under the `Text`, the same width as the `Text` itself.

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
      Text("Finde heraus, was gerade in der Welt los ist.")
           .font(.largeTitle).bold().lineLimit(3).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

      Button(action: {

      }, label: {
           Text("Account erstellen").bold()
               .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
               .frame(height: 40).padding(.top, 0)
               .background(Color.blue)
               .foregroundColor(.white)
               .cornerRadius(20)
      })
}.padding([.leading, .trailing], 25)
```

Which is giving me this result, its pretty ugly in my opinion:

[image]

On the iPad the width between the text and the button is even bigger

How can I solve this issue.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the `bold()` attribute. Removing it caused the text to align as you are expecting. You can try filing a bug, or wait it out and see if it gets fixed over the course of the beta period.

[image: Text aligned with button width]

```
        Text("Finde heraus, was gerade in der Welt los ist.")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .lineLimit(3)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```