# How to get Text width with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I would like to underline a title with a rectangle that should have the same width as the Text.

**First I create an underlined text as below:**

```
struct Title: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Statistics")
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(height: (5.0))
        }
    }

}
```

So I get the following result:

[image]

Now I want to get this result:

[image]

So I would like to know if it's possible to bind Text width and apply it to Rectangle by writing something like :

```
struct Title: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Statistics")
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: Text.width, height: (5.0))
        }
    }

}
```

**By doing so, I could change text and it will be dynamically underlined with correct width.**

I tried many options but I can't find how to do it. I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533428/get-width-of-text-in-swiftui) but it's seems to not be the same issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just specify that container has fixed size and it will tight to content, like

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Statistics")
        Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .frame(height: (5.0))
    }.fixedSize()              // << here !!
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer has helped me with with a weird resize issue I was facing with `.sheet`! For cross-referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525061/swiftui-sheet-view-resizing-issue-testing-on-macos/76526168#76526168