# SwiftUI: Dynamic Label and Image adjust

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-view, swiftui-zstack, swiftui-vstack

We have vertically aligned multiple labels and top tight Image is align to first label.

If first label has not enough content then second label will be move up and vice versa.

image height will be dynamic.

i have also attached image as reference.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [example].

Answer (score 0):

That works if the bell's sizes are fixed, one small and one is big.

Calculate total lenght text for every screen, totalLength = maxLenght - 4 (letters).
With @State var textMaxLenght you can check text lenght for the picture
If textLenght > totalLenght switch state of textMaxLenght.

example:

Maximum view disponible text lenght is 10
For calulate you take 6 (10 - 4, for bell space)
Then if text 7, you compare it with 6, then you will got textMaxLenght = false, and your bell will be small in this case.

Comment: Can you please explore how can we calculate dynamic width and height of the text?? and how many stacks and which kind of stack we can use for swiftUI?

Comment: Just use one of this cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888495/how-to-get-text-width-with-swiftui